# XSL get the element if the element's name AND its attribute equals certain value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How do I translate the below code into a xsl-compilable form?

What I wanted: return the element with the element name == CT AND the CT's attribute == 'person'.

The xsl I tried (but failed):

```
<xsl:if test="CT and @Name='person'">
```

Google keywords are not being very helpful when "And" is involved...

Thanks.

Comment: With (the correct) `xsl:if` instruction you would check if the element exists. The instruction to retrieve nodes and values are those mentioned in @polishchuck answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appropriate XPath: `<xsl:value-of select="CT[@Name = 'person']" />`

Supposed XML:

```
<root>
    <CT Name="a">A</CT>
    <CT Name="person">Person</CT>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//CT[@Name = 'person']" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:
`Person`

Comment: You can also specify that if the copy of the element is need (and not its value) `xsl:copy-of` is necessary.

Comment: You have assumed that the context node is the parent of the CT element. That might or might not be the case.

Comment: @Michael, Yep, I'm not telepathist.